# Video player in qt using Gstreamer or Phonon or VLC Player

Tags: qt, opencv, gstreamer, vlc, phonon

Right now I am in no where :( I want to develop a video player where human will be detected using a detection algorithm which is already working in visual studio platform. My player should simply show the detection in video player. I want use QT framework for that. But the problem is I am not sure which one i should go for. There is option of using Phonon, GStreamer, and vlc player that can be use for my purpose but does anybody has any real experience like this kind of stuff ??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

**GStreamer** is a great cross-platform multimedia framework and I've used it many times, including a few projects involving Qt. Knowing GStreamer certainly adds a great skill to your arsenal but it will take some extra time to understand it's design and how it works.

I've never used **VLC Player**, and **Phonon** should be your last resort [because](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon_%28KDE%29) [it is dying](http://colin.guthr.ie/2010/05/qt-multimediamobility-vs-phonon-fight/).

Another option you might consider is [QtMultimediaKit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0/multimedia.html#video), which is a part of Qt Mobility. It's Qt all the way and may be an easier transition to your current set of skills.

Comment: Could you give additional information behind your comment that Phonon is dying? I'm not challenging you, just curious if this is based on something official you saw in the Qt roadmap, or just a general impression based on something else, like lack of features or progress. Thanks!

Comment: [Even though support for Phonon in Qt will continue for the 4.x series, Qt has already replaced Phonon with QtMultimedia and QtMobility.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon_%28KDE%29)

Comment: [qt-multimediamobility-vs-phonon-fight](http://colin.guthr.ie/2010/05/qt-multimediamobility-vs-phonon-fight/)